# How to auto-resize and fit copy pasted content from a webpage into document file?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I copy pasted some text with tables into an OpenDocument Text file, but for some reason the text, tables and images run off the ride side of the pages. **Is there any way to make LibreOffice to auto-resize and fit all the copy pasted content withing the printable area of pages?**

Answer (score 1):

Try using "`Paste special...`" from the "`Edit`" Menu and pasting the content as "`Unformatted Text`" instead of HTML content. Take care you may loose all formatting by using this paste mode.